# Conditionally add TestNG Listener?

Tags: java, testng

I want to programmatically add different implementations of TestNG Listener based on some conditions.

As I wasn't able to find any means to provide it with some sort of factory via `@Listeners({})` annotation and creating my own TestNG runner does not seem feasible, I've settled on the `IAlterSuiteListener` interface, which, according to documentation:

> allows you to alter a suite (or) a test tag in your suite XML file at
> runtime

To achieve this I've created and registered a simple listener:

```
public class CustomListener implements IExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void onExecutionStart() {
        System.out.println("on start");
    }

    @Override
    public void onExecutionFinish() {
        System.out.println("on finish");
    }
}
```

```
public class AlterSuiteListener implements IAlterSuiteListener {

    @Override
    public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
        for (XmlSuite suite: suites) {
            suite.addListener(String.valueOf(CustomListener.class));
        }
    }
}
```

testng.xml

```
<suite name="all" verbose="1" parallel="tests">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="sandbox.AlterSuiteListener" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="all" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
        <packages>
            <package name="sandbox" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

To make sure `AlterSuiteListener` works I've tried simply changing some suite configuration(setting test timeout) and it does work. Adding listener, however, does not take any effect.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution using ITestNGListenerFactory:

```
public class ConditionalListenerFactory implements ITestNGListenerFactory, ITestNGListener {
    public ConditionalListenerFactory() {
    }

    public ITestNGListener createListener(Class<? extends ITestNGListener> aClass) {
        if(condition()) {
            return new CustomListener();
        }
    }
}
```

And then registering listener via `@Listeners({ConditionalListenerFactory.class})`